# Dynamically generate stages based on conditions in Jenkins groovy script

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

I'm working on a Jenkins pipeline using Groovy script, and I need to dynamically generate stages based on certain conditions. What's the best approach for dynamic stage creation in Jenkins pipeline using Groovy, and are there any examples or recommended patterns?

I'm facing an issue with dynamic stage creation in Jenkins using Groovy. When I try to dynamically create a stage based on the branch name with a line like stage("${branch}"), I get the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 10: Expected a symbol @ line 10, column 5.
                stage("${branch}") {
                ^

1 error
```

I expected this line to dynamically create stages based on the branch, but it seems there's a syntax issue. Any insights on what might be causing this error, and how can I correct it for dynamic stage creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering suggests a syntax issue. To dynamically create stages based on a variable (e.g., branch), you should use double quotes directly without the curly braces. Here's the corrected snippet:

```
stage("${branch}") {
    // Stage content goes here
}
```

Ensure that your Groovy script correctly handles the branch variable or parameter. If the issue persists, check for any other syntax errors in your script and make sure that the branch variable is properly defined or passed to the script.

Comment: Thank you so much @merilstack, this solution actually worked